# Providing validated globals() function in a module

Tags: python

I would like to get filtered globals, and provide them in a function:

```
def my_globals():
    return [y for x, y in globals().items() if not '__' in x]
```

The problem is that when I put it in a module, it does not use the "global" scope, but rather the scope of the module.

I would like to allow a user to specifically access the current "validated" globals. How can I do this?

Comment: The global scope **is** the scope of a module.

Comment: But how to access the scope of where the function is called from?

Comment: @MikeMüller The main module if you will.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the globals of another module, then pass it as a parameter. E.g.:

```
def my_globals(g):
    return [y for x, y in g.items() if not '__' in x]
```

Then call it this way:

```
g = my_globals(globals())
```

To get the caller frame:

```
import inspect
caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
```

To go back more frames in the call stack, use f_back on the frame repeteadly. To get the module of a frame:

```
inspect.getmodule(frame_object)
```

Comment: And how to access when that module is the "main" module? E.g. that person puts in his own function this function, how can I access main?

Comment: In order to access the namespace of a module, you just import that module, and use the dir() function to list its contents. There is `sys.modules` that contains all imported modules. But the "main" module is not special. If your program is a simple, single threaded program then you can extract the module that stands in the root of the call stack. For that, use the traceback module. But frankly, I think you are trying to drive a screw with a hammer...

Comment: I'd be very much interested in how to get that. One of the features on what I'm working is exactly being able to access the root regardless of the current scope.

Comment: Edited the answer to show the frame objects, the inspect module. For format the call strack, use `import traceback`and then `traceback.format_tb`. I still think that you are trying to mess with the internals and you should not do that...

Comment: And remember: there are cases when the root of the call stack won't be your main module. (Just think about threads, asyncio loop, os signal handlers etc.)